# Faster way to get layer information in PyQGIS?

Tags: python, qgis-3, extents

I know that you can quickly access the active layer with `layer = iface.activeLayer()`

Currently I'm working with multiple files in a Python script and my current method of accessing layer extents is this:

```
layer_file = "/path/to/file"
layer_meta = QFileInfo(layer_file)
layer_title = layer_meta.baseName()
layer = QgsRasterLayer(layer_file, layer_title)

layer.extent()
```

I'm just wondering if anyone knows a more efficient way to access the extents of a file without having to reproduce these four lines of code for each file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure there is a shorter code solution but you can refactor your code to use a function like below to avoid repeating the 4 lines everywhere

```py
def get_layer_extent(filepath):
    layer_meta = QFileInfo(filepath)
    layer = QgsRasterLayer(filepath, layer_meta.baseName())
    return layer.extent()

paths = ["/path/to/file1", "/path/to/file2", "/path/to/file3"]

for layer_path in paths:
    print(get_layer_extent(layer_path))
```